# How do you put a StringVar() from a Tkinter Entry box in a re.compile?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a webscraping script that I'd like to operate with a Tkinter GUI.
The script is bascially searching for date ranges and file numbers, so the GUI has Entry boxes which the user inputs their desired numbers.

E.G the strings to search are:

```
feaiuf1939145lkj.1998.foiu0233p3jp.8.3.203f902jall
asdfawefp892u3fp98qp9k.2000.f09389apfa.3.6.983w4pfajsdflkj
afjkwaflfkje.2008.f3ojsdlkjfaof33423.4.5.asodfj
```

My simplified re script would be:

```
extracted_numbers = re.compile(r'.*\.(\d{4})\..*\.(\d\.\d)\..*')
print extracted_numbers.group(1)
print extracted_numbers.group(2)
```

So in Tkinter, I've assigned

```
datebox = StringVar()
filebox = StringVar()
```

How do I put those in the re.compile search string?

Comment: Well what is `re.complie`? You have no example of what that is here so this is not easy to work out.

Comment: It's there in my simplified script: extracted_numbers = re.compile(r'.*\.(\d{4})\..*\.(\d\.\d)\..*')

Comment: Oh I see you are using regular expression. I have not used that in some time. Please build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should include needed imports and a simple tkinter gui that can reproduce the problem.